# React-Native: Tabs inside Tab-Navigation

Tags: android, react-native, tabs, navigation

I'm currently using a tab-navigation to switch between screens. I want to add tabs inside a screen.

Example: Tab-Navigation has 'Home', 'Search' and 'Profile'. Now I want to add a tab-navigation (as a sub-menu) into 'Profile' with 'Me' and 'Settings'.

Does someone know how to do this? I only found solutions to add a tabs inside a stack-navigation.

Comment: I faced same issue, so I end up using [react-native-scrollable-tab-view](https://github.com/skv-headless/react-native-scrollable-tab-view) inside inside `Tab-Navigation`.

Answer (score 0):

Using [react-navigation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-navigation) as the main app level tabs, you can use [react-native-tab-view](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-tab-view) to have "sub" tabs on the particular screen/page.

This looks good enough for Android. For iOS I don't use [SegmentedControlIOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/segmentedcontrolios.html) to have a tab like switch effect